# jquery validator add method

Tags: jquery, validation

I am having an issue getting this to work. On our form we validate zip code (postal code) length based on the country you select. Australia and Hungary have min length of 4 characters, Bahrain must have at least 3 and all other countries must have at least 5. So I wrote a rule for:

Australia

```
$.validator.addMethod("AusZip", function(value, element) {
    var isAus = $("#UpdateCountry").val() === "AUS";
    if ( isAus && value.length < 4 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Australian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");
```

Hungary

```
$.validator.addMethod("HunZip", function(value, element) {
    var isHun = $("#UpdateCountry").val() === "HUN";
    if ( isHun && value.length < 4 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Hungarian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");
```

and Bahrain

```
$.validator.addMethod("BHRZip", function(value, element) {
    var isBHR = $("#UpdateCountry").val() === "BHR";
    if ( isBHR && value.length < 3 ) {
        return false;
} else return true;
}, "Bahrain Zip Code Must Be at least 3 Digits");
```

All other countries specified here, and this is where my problem is

```
$.validator.addMethod("RegZip", function(value, element) {
    var notAus = $("#UpdateCountry").val() != "AUS";
    var notBHR = $("#UpdateCountry").val() != "BHR";
    var notHun = $("#UpdateCountry").val() != "HUN";
    if ( notAus && notBHR && notHun && value.length < 5 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Zip Code Must Be at least 5 Digits");
```

When I add the rule for "RegZip" even if you select Australia or Hungary and have a 4 digit zip, you get the error - same if you select Hungary and have a 3 digit zip. When I remove "RegZip" you only get an error with Australia/Hungary if it's less than 4 digits and error on Hungary if less than 3. The problem is that all other countries have no requirement. What am I missing?

thx!

EDIT - added "UpdateCountry" as the element ID. works. sorry for confusion - my bad!

Comment: could you create a fiddle please ?

Comment: @mcgrailm - here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gYs2Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this would be something like so:

```
 var zips = {
  'AUS': { min: 4 },
  'HUN': { min: 4 },
  'BHR': { min: 3 }

};
var zipOther = { min: 5 };

$.validator.addMethod('zip', function(value, element) {
  return value.length >= (zips[$('#UpdateCountry').val()] || zipOther)['min'];
}, 'Zip code not the correct length');
```

Comment: what is the .toUpperCase(); line for? to ensure values are uppercase, they all are already on the select list - am I missing something? I have a fiddle of it here jsfiddle.net/gYs2Y

Comment: I've removed the .toUpperCase(). Also Bahrain is BHR in your country list. I'm not too familiar with validator plugin, there is probably a better way to do this native to that plugin, I'm not just seeing it right now. :)

Comment: I like this method and will use it going forward. the error I had wasn't due to my validation rules themselves, but had an incorrectly named element.

Comment: Thanks. If you want to have a more custom error message which relates to that country try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QmYsd/

Comment: really awesome, easy to add to. Could you explain the fiddle example a little though? thx

Answer (score 1):

With the code you provided you are only validating the three countries in the `RegZip` function as everything else returns true. You should have some other generic zip validation being calling in the `else` clause.

Comment: could you expand on that. Those are the only three countries that have special requirements, all other countries should have a min length of 5. I think I understand what you mean, could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of all your checks on $("#Country").val() and simple change the class name on the input on change of Country select

**EDIT**

first add class "RegZip' to the input you want to validate as starting point

then add validator methods

```
$.validator.addMethod("AusZip", function(value, element) {
    if (value.length < 4 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Australian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");

//Hungary

$.validator.addMethod("HunZip", function(value, element) {
    if (value.length < 4 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Hungarian Zip Code Must Be at least 4 Digits");

//and Bahrain

$.validator.addMethod("BHRZip", function(value, element) {
    if (value.length < 3 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Bahrain Zip Code Must Be at least 3 Digits");

//All other countries specified here, and this is where my problem is

$.validator.addMethod("RegZip", function(value, element) {
    if ( notAus && notBHR && notHun && value.length < 5 ) {
        return false;
    } else return true;
}, "Zip Code Must Be at least 5 Digits");
```

add change event to dropdown list

```
$('#dropdown_menu_selector').onchange(function(){
    if (this.value === "AUS"){
        $('#input_to_validate').removeClass().addClass('AUSZip')
    }
    //etc etc..
});
```

validate the form

```
   $('#formid').validate();
```

Comment: so add a class for each countries length (Aus, Hun length 4 class="four" - all others length 5 class="five" etc) and validate the length against the class?

Comment: how does adding a class help? Not sure I follow.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design because the validate will act on class names via validate method